# Zombie getting error Unhandled rejection Error: Timeout: did not get to load all resources on this page

Tags: javascript, node.js, zombie.js

I am new to zombie JS. I want to fill the login fields and post the login form. I tried to code this in zombiejs, but getting below error.

Unhandled rejection Error: Timeout: did not get to load all resources on this page
    at timeout (C:\Users\sapna.maid\Desktop\nodejs\index\node_modules\zombie\lib
\eventloop.js:601:38)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)

My code snippet is as below:

```
var zombie = require("zombie");
zombie.waitDuration = '30s';
//Browser.waitDuration = '300s';
var assert = require("assert");

browser = new zombie({
    maxWait: 10000,
    waitDuration: 30*1000,
    silent: true
});
browser.visit("https://example.com", function () {
    // fill search query field with value "zombie"
    console.log("LOADEDDDD !!!!", browser.location.href);
    console.log(this.browser.text('title'));
    assert.equal(this.browser.text('title'), 'Welcome - Sign In');
    browser.fill('#user', 'user@example.com');
    browser.fill('#pass', 'pass@123');

    browser.document.forms[0].submit();


    console.log(browser.text('title'));
    // wait for new page to be loaded then fire callback function
    browser.wait(5000).then(function() {
    // just dump some debug data to see if we're on the right page
    console.log(this.browser.success);
    assert.ok(this.browser.success);
    console.log("Browser title:: --------- " + this.browser.text('title'));
    assert.equal(this.browser.text('title'), 'Dashboard');
    })
});
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.
I am stuck here for long duration.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that the assertion below fails since the `www.example.com`'s title is `Example Domain` not `Welcome - Sign In`

```
assert.equal(this.browser.text('title'), 'Welcome - Sign In');
```

Moreover, these lines will most probably also fail since there are no elements with such ids on the page.

```
browser.fill('#user', 'user@example.com');
browser.fill('#pass', 'pass@123');
```

Comment: Hi mic4ael,
Thanks for reply.
I have used "www.example.com" just for placeholder of my domain.
I have made it sure that my domain do have "#user" and "#pass" ids.
Assuming that the my domain has the title "Welcome - Sign In" and given ids are valid, please help me to solve the issue mentioned.

Comment: is your domain available publicly?

Comment: Yes. Its available.I can able to click link, but not able to submit login request/submit the form.
I have refereed some blogs but not able to resolve the issue.Below is the one URL for the issue.
https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/882